# Objective-C Code to C Code

Tags: objective-c, c

How can I "compile" Objective-C Code to (only) C-Code?
There is a way to preprocess Objective-C in Xcode (Product -> Generate Output -> Generate Preprocessed File), but this is not what I'm looking for...

Thanks...

Comment: you are aware of that objc and c are completely different languages right?

Comment: Yes, but i meant the Objective-C code is converted into C... Or not?

Comment: if there was a tool that could convert between very different languages by just pushing a button (from object orientated to non-oo etc) I would be out of work

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question.  In fact, the original version of Objective-C was nothing more than a pre-compiler that spit out straight C code and a small runtime that went with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clang (the compiler front-end used by Xcode nowadays) has a `-rewrite-objc` option built-in, which allows you to generate C++ code based on Objective-C (or Objective-C++) code.

Just don't ask me how to combine that with Xcode.